# how to iterate through string and get the second last number

Tags: php, string

I need second last number from the list and the list can have varied length. I tried seperating it using explode(",", $layouts);

```
$layouts= '1,0,2,0,3,0,4,0,5,0,6,0,7,0,8,0,9,0,10,0,11,0,12,0,13,0,14,0,15,0,16,0,17,0,18,0,19,0,20,0,21,0,22,0,23,0,24,0,25,0,26,0,27,0,28,0,29,0,30,0';
```

Example : I need to get 30 from the string here.
please help

Comment: One way that springs to mind is `array_slice(explode(",", $layouts), -2, 1)[0]`

Comment: Why do you need only 30? is there a criteria used; or is this list having fixed length at all time so you can confidently use location indexes? Anyway, explode the string into array, then use the right index to get the value you want from the array.

Comment: I need second last number from the list and the  list can have varied length

Answer (score 2):

If this list can grow in size as you have indicated in the comment, then usually explode it into an array, then do a count of the size, subtract two from the total size and use that as an index to get the value:

```
//turn this to array 
$layouts = '1,0,2,0,3,0,4,0,5,0,6,0,7,0,8,0,9,0,10,0,11,0,12,0,13,0,14,0,15,0,16,0,17,0,18,0,19,0,20,0,21,0,22,0,23,0,24,0,25,0,26,0,27,0,28,0,29,0,30,0';
$layoutsArray = explode(",", $layouts);
$xtarget = count($layoutsArray) - 2;
$xvalue = "";
if($xtarget > -1){
   $xvalue = $layoutsArray[$xtarget];
}else {
   //it could be wrong
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can explode it with , and get 2nd last value from array try the following code

```
$layouts= '1,0,2,0,3,0,4,0,5,0,6,0,7,0,8,0,9,0,10,0,11,0,12,0,13,0,14,0,15,0,16,0,17,0,18,0,19,0,20,0,21,0,22,0,23,0,24,0,25,0,26,0,27,0,28,0,29,0,30,0';

$array = explode(',',$layouts);
if(count($array) > 2){
    $pair = array_slice($array, -2, 1, true);
    $key = key($pair);
    $value = current($pair);

    echo $value;    
}
```

Output

```
30
```